# qtip content button unable change div display & text readonly attribute

Tags: jquery, html, qtip

I am having problem with qtip content button. When i try to change a text's readonly property to, it change the property by it is still writeabl. and same problem when i am trying to display a div using on click.

Here is [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2xMB/12/) link to the problem....

Comment: how do you want to click on a hidden element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qtip clones your html for the Tooltip and then displays it as and when, meaning your id wont always be unique.

Instead using the class

```
 $(document).on("click",'.poster', function() {
        $('.lookup').attr('readOnly', true);     
    });
```

Will disable the textfield when you click the go button

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2xMB/19/)